# recalculate mean considering each count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

if the dataframe is given as below

```
index yearmon   college major   gpa     num
0     20140401  1       a       3.36    29
1     20180401  2       b       2.63    48
2     20160401  3       c       3.23    55
3     20170401  4       d       4.22    1
4     20140401  3       b       3.72    72
```

which gives the average gpa of each year, each college, each major.

i want to make a new data set as average gpa only considering the major.

for example for major b, there is 2 data in different time,

so i have to make a new
gpa average **considering the num (number of students)**

i have tried groupby function, but it only makes average as they have same num count (not considering num variable)

is there way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lazy way, given that the number of students are integers,

```
(df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['num']), ['major', 'gpa']]
   .groupby('major').mean()
)
```

---

**Option 2** `groupby().apply()` and `np.average`:

```
(df.groupby('major')
   .apply(lambda x: np.average(x['gpa'], weights=x['num']))
)
```

---

**Option 3** Most complicated but best performant is to assign the total score, and calculate the average manually:

```
df['total'] = df['gpa'] * df['num']
groups = df.groupby('major')
out = groups['total'].sum()/groups['num'].sum()
```

---

**Output**:

```
         gpa
major       
a      3.360
b      3.284
c      3.230
d      4.220
```