# How to transpose values in one column to columns using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Hi there I have a data set look like df1 below and I want to make it look like df2 using pandas. I have tried to use pivot and transpose but can't wrap my head around how to do it. Appreciate any help!

[image: df1]

[image: df2]

Comment: Paste the DF as code instead of images please. You can look at how they've pasted it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67394649/recalculate-mean-considering-each-count

Comment: Have you tried `pandas.pivot_table()`? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job

```
    df.pivot_table(index=["AssetID"], columns='MeterName', values='MeterValue')
```

index: Identifier

columns: row values that will become columns

values: values to put in those columns

I often have the same trouble:
https://towardsdatascience.com/reshape-pandas-dataframe-with-pivot-table-in-python-tutorial-and-visualization-2248c2012a31

This could help next time.